# How to see the structure of a file

Tags: visual-studio

I am a very recent user of Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. In most Ides, there is a structural view of the current file. For example in IntelliJ Idea, one can see the data members and functions in a class file. Or one can see the hierarchical structure of an html file. I could not find such a view in Visual Studio upto now. There is a list of functions above the file editor. But this doesn't work in in cshtml files.

Is there such a structural view in VS? If so how to access it?

Comment: I've never used either, but would a Class Diagram fit your needs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hyxd8c85.aspx

Comment: For file layout: View\Solution Explorer. For Class layout: View\Class View. And surely you mean VS 2012, not 2013...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. "Class View" is what I am looking for. One more question: How can it automatically show the class view of the currently open file in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to "View/Class View" menu item to get the class view window.

The class view window does not auto-sync. However, you can go to the "Tools/Options" menu item, then go to the "Environment/Keyboard" tree item. Under the "Show Commands Containing", search for "View.SynchornizeClassView". You can then assign this to some key combination which you can then use to sync it.